# Oracle SQL first and last day of quarter of any year

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there any way i can calculate the first and last day of the three quarters in any year . 2012 , 2013 or 2014

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Q'), -3) AS First,
       TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Q') - 1             AS Last
FROM DUAL
```

calculates the first quarter of current year. i want to calculate the first quarter of any year ?

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following:

```
with q(qtr) as(
  select add_months(
                    DATE '2013-01-01'
                    , (level-1)*3
                    )
    from dual 
  connect by level <= 4
)
select qtr                          as first_day
     , last_day(add_months(qtr, 2)) as last_day
  from q
```

Result:

```
FIRST_DAY     LAST_DAY
-----------  -----------
01.01.2013    31.03.2013
01.04.2013    30.06.2013
01.07.2013    30.09.2013
01.10.2013    31.12.2013
```

[**SQLFIddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/16695)

Comment: Hi this is not what  i want. This is calculating the quarter of the current year. i want to find the quarter of any year.

Comment: @ManviKapoor To display different year part of the `first_day` and `last_day` value, you could just change `trunc(sysdate, 'Y')` to `trunc(add_months(sysdate, [+-]12 * num_of_years_from_current_year), 'Y')`.

Comment: what is num_of_years_from_current_year?

Comment: Hope you don't mind Nicholas - I've updated the example query to show how to get the quarters for any given year, which will hopefully be simpler for the OP.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Absolutely not, Jeffrey. It's simpler, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing it

```
select  to_date('01-JAN-'||to_char(yr), 'DD-MON-YYYY') first_qtr,
   to_date('01-APR-'||to_char(yr), 'DD-MON-YYYY') second_qtr,
   to_date('01-JUL-'||to_char(yr), 'DD-MON-YYYY') third_qtr,
   to_date('01-OCT-'||to_char(yr), 'DD-MON-YYYY') fourth_qtr
   from ( select :year yr from dual )
UNION ALL
select to_date('01-APR-'||to_char(yr), 'DD-MON-YYYY')-1 first_qtr,
   to_date('01-JUL-'||to_char(yr), 'DD-MON-YYYY')-1 second_qtr,
   to_date('01-OCT-'||to_char(yr), 'DD-MON-YYYY')-1 third_qtr,
   to_date('01-JAN-'||to_char(yr+1), 'DD-MON-YYYY')-1 fourth_qtr
   from ( select :year yr from dual )
```

I have used  bind variables so change it to your requirements accordingly.

I am fairly new to Oracle, so other's can give a simplified code.

The output when given 2009 would be as below

```
FIRST_QTR   SECOND_QTR  THIRD_QTR   FOURTH_QTR
01/01/2009  04/01/2009  07/01/2009  10/01/2009
03/31/2009  06/30/2009  09/30/2009  12/31/2009
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but maybe this will be helpful:

```
WITH y1 AS (
    SELECT LEVEL + 2000 AS the_year
      FROM dual
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 20
), q1 AS (
    SELECT LEVEL AS the_quarter
      FROM dual
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4
)
SELECT the_year, the_quarter
     , TO_CHAR(first_day, 'DAY') AS first_dw, first_day
     , TO_CHAR(last_day, 'DAY') AS last_dw, last_day
  FROM (
    SELECT the_year, the_quarter
         , ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(the_year, 'YYYY'), 3 * (the_quarter - 1)) AS first_day
         , ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(the_year, 'YYYY'), 3 * the_quarter) - 1 AS last_day
      FROM y1, q1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

One line per year, each line consisting of the year plus 8 (=2 dates per quarter) dates:

```
with params as (
  select
    2012 as start_year,
    2014 as end_year
  from
    dual
)
select
           start_year+ level - 1                          year,
  to_date((start_year+ level - 1) || '0101', 'yyyymmdd')  start_q1,
  to_date((start_year+ level - 1) || '0331', 'yyyymmdd')  end_q1  ,
  to_date((start_year+ level - 1) || '0401', 'yyyymmdd')  start_q2,
  to_date((start_year+ level - 1) || '0630', 'yyyymmdd')  end_q2  ,
  to_date((start_year+ level - 1) || '0701', 'yyyymmdd')  start_q3,
  to_date((start_year+ level - 1) || '0930', 'yyyymmdd')  end_q3  ,
  to_date((start_year+ level - 1) || '1001', 'yyyymmdd')  start_q4,
  to_date((start_year+ level - 1) || '1231', 'yyyymmdd')  end_q4
from
  dual, params
connect by
  start_year + level -1 <= end_year;
```