# SQL - How to update a column's date to the last day of the year of another column

Tags: sql, oracle, date

If I have an effective from date and an effective to date column, how do I make the effective to date column equal the last day of the year of whatever year is in the effective from date?

Here is what I have (but much longer):

```
eff from      eff to

01/01/2013    12/31/2013
03/15/2007    03/31/2007
10/21/2014    10/20/2015
06/01/2005    05/31/2006
```

Here is what I want:

```
eff from      eff to

01/01/2013    12/31/2013
03/15/2007    12/31/2007
10/21/2014    12/31/2014
06/01/2005    12/31/2005
```

Trying to do update the eff to column setting it to 12-31-YYYY using the YYYY of the eff from column

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551333/oracle-sql-first-and-last-day-of-quarter-of-any-year

Answer (score 0):

This query might work for you:

```
update table_name set effective_date = last_day(add_months(from_date,12 - to_number(to_char(sysdate,'mm'))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since 12/31 is always the last date of the year... extract the year concat a string and convert back to a date.

```
Update TableName 
Set "EFF TO" = 
 to_date(extract(year from TO_DATE("eff from", 'yyyy/mm/dd'))||'12/31','yyyy/mm/dd') 
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a handy reference with a bunch of first day/last day date manipulations for Oracle:  http://programmerslounge.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-get-first-day-and-last-day-of.html

You can simply:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET eff_to = LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC("eff_from", 'Year'),11));
```

`TRUNC()` with 'Year' gets you the first day of each year, adding 11 months to that gets you the first of December, and `LAST_DAY()` takes you to the end of the month.

Answer (score 0):

```
update myTable set effTo = Date_Sub( 
    Date_add( 
     MakeDate(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM effFrom),1), 
     interval 1 year), 
     interval 1 day)
```